# How can I make this type of pattern on a rounded surface

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I was browsing the internet, and saw this triangle shape around a cylinder shape.  I  use a Boolean modifier to make cuts around the shape, and get bad shading because its triangles. So what method could I use to make this section indicated in Red.

I did the pattern of triangles, then added solidify modifier. I try Boolean, but Blender crashes.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Make it flat, array and simple deform modifier with bend option, then weld.

Comment: There's also a procedural material tutorial from Ryan King which might give you the result you want and doesn't require a high poly count: https://youtu.be/78fay5ZVACs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a 6 vertex circle, *Fill Type > Triangle Fans*, add two triangles on its right:

[image]

Select all, inset the individual faces (<kbd>i</kbd>i) and remove the inset faces, add some loopcuts:

[image]

Array on X and Z, don't forget to enable the *Merge* option:

[image]

Give it a *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode, on Z, a bit more than 360°), also a *Weld* modifier so that the first and last instance merge:

[image]

Put a *Solidify* modifier before the *Weld* to give thickness to the object, shade smooth and auto smooth to get a good shading:

[image]

Comment: Mega Thanks Moonboots!